# Count total number of git commits from packfile

Tags: git

I have a bundle that contains git packfile. 
 From what I could find by now, I initialised an empty git repo and copied that packfile in .git/objects folder. 
 After that, I executed git unpack-objects to extract the content of the packfile. 
 Now the question is how can I get the total number of commits that are in that packfile?
I tried using a tool like git-sizer, and I am getting the following output

```
.git % git-sizer -v       
Processing blobs: 8                        
Processing trees: 3                        
Processing commits: 1                        
Matching commits to trees: 1                        
Processing annotated tags: 0                        
Processing references: 1                        
| Name                         | Value     | Level of concern               |
| ---------------------------- | --------- | ------------------------------ |
| Overall repository size      |           |                                |
| * Commits                    |           |                                |
|   * Count                    |     1     |                                |
|   * Total size               |   177 B   |                                |
| * Trees                      |           |                                |
|   * Count                    |     3     |                                |
|   * Total size               |   567 B   |                                |
|   * Total tree entries       |    11     |                                |
| * Blobs                      |           |                                |
|   * Count                    |     8     |                                |
|   * Total size               |  69.3 MiB |                                |
| * Annotated tags             |           |                                |
|   * Count                    |     0     |                                |
| * References                 |           |                                |
|   * Count                    |     1     |                                |
|     * Branches               |     1     |                                |
|                              |           |                                |
| Biggest objects              |           |                                |
| * Commits                    |           |                                |
|   * Maximum size         [1] |   177 B   |                                |
|   * Maximum parents      [1] |     0     |                                |
| * Trees                      |           |                                |
|   * Maximum entries      [2] |     5     |                                |
| * Blobs                      |           |                                |
|   * Maximum size         [3] |  52.5 MiB | *****                          |
|                              |           |                                |
| History structure            |           |                                |
| * Maximum history depth      |     1     |                                |
| * Maximum tag depth          |     0     |                                |
|                              |           |                                |
| Biggest checkouts            |           |                                |
| * Number of directories  [2] |     3     |                                |
| * Maximum path depth     [2] |     3     |                                |
| * Maximum path length    [2] |    65 B   |                                |
| * Number of files        [2] |     9     |                                |
| * Total size of files    [2] |  69.3 MiB |                                |
| * Number of symlinks         |     0     |                                |
| * Number of submodules       |     0     |                                |

[1]  73d9a3662c9e52c39e8efbfa40a48e39f143d72e (refs/heads/master)
[2]  7a244cc36e07929f2714296021c7605daaf28542 (refs/heads/master^{tree})
[3]  6cbe51484efd47cd119ba9d54bc87061cc140b63 (refs/heads/master:objects/pack/pack-c1117410d7ff71062c25e2e4f3dd86ebffca897b.pack)
```

and that one commit that is displaying is the one that I made, but there should be much much more..
is there any way to get the total commits number?

Comment: What about `git rev-list --count`?

Comment: what should I pass to it? just by passing the 3 hash ids from the bottom of git-sizer I do not get any number besides the one commit that I made?

Comment: pass a head? eg `HEAD` or `master`

Comment: still the same, either 0 or 1

Comment: and what about `git rev-list --all --count`? (Also, how do you know there are definitely more commits in the packfile?)

Comment: "I have a bundle" like a `.tgz` archive ? or a bundle created with `git bundle` ?

Comment: Josh - still only shows one commit, as for the second question, it should have at least 1000 commits, because we made them, but on a different system.
LeGEC - .tgz archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Git pack file contains objects, but objects by themselves are not useful.

A Git *repository* consists of *two* databases (plus ancillary files, plus other options, but the two databases are the key here):

- One database holds all the objects.  These may be in a single pack file, in multiple pack files, and/or present as "loose" objects.  They're not useful without the other database!
- The other database contains *names*.  These names *reference* objects.  For some name-types, the referenced objects may be any of the four types, but for branch and remote-tracking names, the referenced objects must be *commits*.

A reference *to* a commit makes that commit "reachable".  A *reachable* commit can be found.

A commit itself contains two things:

- Directly, the commit contains metadata.  This metadata refers to a single `tree` object, and has a list of `parent` object references (typically one entry long but it can be zero entries long, or more than one entry long).
- Indirectly, via the `tree` object, the commit contains files: that's the snapshot that goes with the commit.

Because a commit *can* and usually *does* refer to some other previous ("parent") commit, a reachable commit makes the referred-to commit *also* reachable.  That is, if the name `master` locates commit `a123456...`, and commit `a123456` says that its parent is `b789abc...`, then at least *two* commits are reachable.

> Now the question is how can I get the total number of commits that are in that packfile?

The number of commits in the packfile isn't really interesting: only the number of *reachable* commits is interesting.  There is therefore no easy way to count the specific commit objects.  However, if you really want to do that, you can *unpack* the objects with `git unpack-objects`.  There are some constraints here so you'd want to do this by unpacking into a new, empty repository, to turn every object that's in the pack into a loose object.  It's now easy enough to find every object (`find .git/objects -type f -print` and deal with the funky name organization) and then use `git cat-file -t` or similar to find the *type* of each such object (for efficiency, use `git cat-file --batch-check`).  That will allow you to separate the overall count into individual object-type counts.

You could also use `git fsck --unreachable` here, which won't require unpacking the objects first.  All the commits will be unreachable after copying the pack file into this temporary, empty Git repository.